# Jquery invalid regular expression flag r?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using codeignitor with jquery.

My JS is as following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var p = {};
   $('#content').load(/mycontroller/myfunction,p,function(str){
    });
 });
```

It gave me an invalid regular expression flag r error on line 3.
I am not sure it is a JS error, or the codeignitor mod_rewrite issue.

Can someone please shred some lights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `.load()` function takes a url in the form of a string.

```
var p = {};
  $('#content').load("/mycontroller/myfunction",p,function(str){
});
```

Comment: @Shadow_boi it's been a while, but if an answer was the correct one, you should set is an accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

You need quotes around the path:

```
"/mycontroller/myfunction"
```